# Scattering from a step potential barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

Suppose a potential barrier of the form
$$
V(x) = \begin{cases} V_0 & x>0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{cases}
$$
Then, for energy $E$ such that $E < V_0$, we have that the transmission and reflection coefficients for the probabilities are $R = 1, T = 0$. In case where $V_0$ is not enormously large with respect to $E$, wave function will decay in $x>0$, but in a somewhat not rapid fashion. This means there is some reasonable not negligible probability for the particle to tunnel through. How does this agree with the fact that $R=1$, which means **all** of the probability has been reflected?

Comment: Apologies if I am wrong, but is what you described above an infinitely wide barrier? Which would explain the R equals 1.

Comment: Yes, I understand mathematically why $R=1$, I am trying to understand the physical meaning of this, given that there is some probability for the particle to tunnel (even though $R = 1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ and $R$ are transmission and reflection coefficients for *waves*. They refer to the probability that an incident wave will penetrate the barrier and continue propagating infinitely far. Physically, you should think of it as sending a constant sine wave in from the far left and looking to see what amplitude of constant sine wave you get at the far right.

In this case, since $E < V_0$ no matter how far to the right you go, the amplitude keeps decaying exponentially for all positive $x$. It never recovers its sinusoidal form, as it would with a rectangular barrier of finite extent, so there is no transmission.

Now, if you think of this waves as probability waves, then yes, it seems like there is a chance that the particle will materialize inside the barrier. And there is. That doesn't count as transmission, though. The process of a wave "turning into a particle" (i.e. wavefunction collapse) is not taken into account by the calculation of the transmission and reflection coefficients.